How to use Bloc with Freezed package while running 2 api requests? What is best approach?
can someone explain what solution I can implement in this issue?
I have one screen, where I have two requests (later there will be more requests). I thought the best approach is to separate this two request into two different methods and then call initFetch. But something is not working good. At the end, I am running two requests, but one of them is always with error.
One more thing. In future probably I`ll be using this requests separately.
So, my Bloc is
  ObjectsBloc({required this.objectsUseCase, required this.balanceUseCase})
  : super(const ObjectsState.initial()) {
on<ObjectsEvent>((event, emit) async {
  await event.when(
    fetchObjects: () async => await _fetchObjects(emit),
    fetchBalance: () async => await _fetchBalance(emit),
  );
});

and I`ve created State like this
class ObjectsState with _$ObjectsState {
  const factory ObjectsState.initial() = _Initial;

  const factory ObjectsState.objectsLoading() = _ObjectsLoading;
  const factory ObjectsState.objectsLoaded(ObjectsListResponse objects) = 
  _ObjectsLoaded;
  const factory ObjectsState.objectsError(String message) = _ObjectsError;

  const factory ObjectsState.balanceLoading() = _BalanceLoading;
  const factory ObjectsState.balanceLoaded(BalanceResponse balance) = _BalanceLoaded;
  const factory ObjectsState.balanceError(String message) = _BalanceError;
}

And event
class ObjectsEvent with _$ObjectsEvent {
 const factory ObjectsEvent.fetchObjects() = _FetchObjects;
 const factory ObjectsEvent.fetchBalance() = _FetchBalance;
}

Or maybe I should use different Bloc for this? One for balance and one for object?
